# Port Atom Extension to VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, vscode-extensions

VS Code is built using electron, same tool used for Atom.

I have an extension in Atom that

1. when user hits tab, it queries a rest api
2. and puts the result on the editor

Is there a way I can port this extension to VS Code?

Developing the VS Code extension from scratch would be too much work I guess.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is quite vague. If you have you tried porting it and come up against a specific issue then that would be a more appropriate question.

Comment: @phuzi Its not vague as there must be some way you can do this quite simply, at least could you tell how to port it?

Comment: @Rafael you would be best to start by looking at how to create VSCode extensions. They are built using TypeScript, not Javascript. So already it's using a different language. Next its got a whole different set of API endpoints to access and use for its various features. The two editors are nothing alike so porting them isn't a simple task.
phuzi was right to ask for more specific issues you may be having because you need to first start somewhere and there's a lot to do to port it. OIts not as easy as just changing a few settings and 'plonking' it in VSCode.